# class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive

Tags: ignite

After fiddling with the basic cluster, I tried another example for native persistence in Ignite by adding the below configuration in a fresh cluster.

```
    <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

However, I am unable to do create/insert/update/delete operations. I am facing the following error:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive. Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster. To activate the cluster call Ignite.active(true).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:2017)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1979)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.executeQuery(JdbcRequestHandler.java:310)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.jdbc.JdbcRequestHandler.handle(JdbcRequestHandler.java:169)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:148)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:41)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cluster needs to be explicitly activated if persistence is used. See details here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-activation

Comment: visor> top command before and after activation of cluster helped me verify if the cluster is running or not.

$IGNITE_HOME/bin/control.sh --activate